# SELECT DISTINCT on a ordered subquery's table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm working on a problem, involving these two tables.

```
               books
isbn    |                  title                  |      author      
------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------
1840918626 | Hogwarts: A History                     | Bathilda Bagshot
3458400871 | Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them | Newt Scamander
9136884926 | Advanced Potion-Making                  | Libatius Borage


              transactions
id | patron_id |    isbn    | checked_out_date | checked_in_date 
----+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------
1 |         1 | 1840918626 | 2012-05-05       | 2012-05-06
2 |         4 | 9136884926 | 2012-05-05       | 2012-05-06
3 |         2 | 3458400871 | 2012-05-05       | 2012-05-06
4 |         3 | 3458400871 | 2018-04-29       | 2018-05-02
5 |         2 | 9136884926 | 2018-05-03       | NULL
6 |         1 | 3458400871 | 2018-05-03       | 2018-05-05
7 |         5 | 3458400871 | 2018-05-05       | NULL
```

the query "Make a list of all book titles and denote whether or not a copy of that book is checked out." so pretty much just the first table with a checked out column.

im trying to SELECT DISTINCT on a sub query with the checkout books first, but that doesn't work. I've researched and others say to accomplish this use a GROUP BY clause instead of DISTINCT but the examples they provide are one column queries and when more columns are added it doesn't work.

this is my closest attempt

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (title)
title, checked_out
FROM(
  SELECT b.title, t.checked_in_date IS NULL AS checked_out
  FROM transactions t
  natural join books b
  ORDER BY checked_out DESC
) t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can join only transactions where books are not checked in:

```
SELECT b.title, t.isbn IS NOT NULL AS checked_out
, t.checked_out_date
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.isbn = b.isbn AND t.checked_in_date IS NULL
ORDER BY checked_out DESC
```

Comment: I didn't think of doing this, it solved my problem actually and is much cleaner than what I had done.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your attempt a little bit. Basically I changed the way your data is joined

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (title)
title, checked_out
FROM(
  SELECT b.title, t.checked_in_date IS NULL AS checked_out
  FROM books b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t USING (isbn)
  ORDER BY checked_out DESC
) t;
```